# Как посчитать общую стоимость заказов на ежемесячной основе в разбивке по странам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Первая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country
0   536365  85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER  6   12/1/2010 8:26  2.55    17850.0 United Kingdom
1   536365  71053   WHITE METAL LANTERN 6   12/1/2010 8:26  3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom
2   536365  84406B  CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER  8   12/1/2010 8:26  2.75    17850.0 United Kingdom
3   536365  84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE 6   12/1/2010 8:26  3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom
4   536365  84029E  RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.  6   12/1/2010 8:26  3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom
```

Дальше я ставлю индексом `InvoiceDate` и удаляю столбец `InvoiceDate`:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.InvoiceDate)
data.drop('InvoiceDate', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Дальше не получается из-за того, что `resampling` удаляет текстовые столбцы, а мне нужен столбец `Country`. Так тоже не выходит:

```
data.groupby(['Country'](key='InvoiceDate', freq='m')).sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=["InvoiceDate"], encoding="latin-1")

res = (df.eval("Amount = Quantity * UnitPrice")
         .groupby(["Country", pd.Grouper(key="InvoiceDate", freq="MS")])
         ["Amount"]
         .sum())
```

---

результат:

```
In [8]: res
Out[8]:
Country      InvoiceDate
Australia    2010-12-01      1005.10
             2011-01-01      9017.71
             2011-02-01     14627.47
             2011-03-01     17055.29
             2011-04-01       333.40
             2011-05-01     13628.51
             2011-06-01     25164.77
                              ...
Unspecified  2011-04-01       299.10
             2011-05-01      1055.87
             2011-06-01       185.78
             2011-07-01      1425.41
             2011-08-01       531.03
             2011-09-01       286.85
             2011-11-01       965.75
Name: Amount, Length: 314, dtype: float64
```

или:

```
In [9]: res.reset_index()
Out[9]:
         Country InvoiceDate       Amount
0      Australia  2010-12-01      1005.10
1      Australia  2011-01-01      9017.71
2      Australia  2011-02-01     14627.47
3      Australia  2011-03-01     17055.29
4      Australia  2011-04-01       333.40
5      Australia  2011-05-01     13628.51
6      Australia  2011-06-01     25164.77
..           ...         ...          ...
307  Unspecified  2011-04-01       299.10
308  Unspecified  2011-05-01      1055.87
309  Unspecified  2011-06-01       185.78
310  Unspecified  2011-07-01      1425.41
311  Unspecified  2011-08-01       531.03
312  Unspecified  2011-09-01       286.85
313  Unspecified  2011-11-01       965.75

[314 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: KeyError: 'The grouper name InvoiceDate is not found'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282691/pandas-grouper-issue-with-key-that-is-an-index

Comment: @svil, Обратите внимание на то как я читаю данные. В вашем случае InvoiceDate является индексом, а в моем нет.

Comment: Делаю без индекса и ошибка Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: `res = (data.eval("Amount = Quantity * UnitPrice")
         .groupby(["Country", pd.Grouper(key="InvoiceDate", freq="MS")])
         ["Amount"]
         .sum())`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13qNaA3BV3aVhwYf89xok8ejucO8zNKAD здесь мой csv файл

Comment: Загружаю я его  так `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',  encoding='cp1250')`

Comment: @svil, попробуйте запустить код из ответа, только подставьте имя файла вместо `url` - этот ответ протестирован...

Comment: Да из ответа работает. Только долго считает как будто завис, я только по вкладке браузера с иконкой песочных часов методом тыка поняла, что считает.

Comment: @svil, для вашей задачи вам не нужно делать `InvoiceDate` индексом...

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Wu7jdfwKdFb-bChigM_XdqUIjqvrlpf Тот же код в Colab не разбивает ежемесячно по странам. Берет только декабрь, а в jupiter все месяцы выводит.

Comment: По умолчанию в Colab freq='A-DEC' наверно, как настроить, чтоб все месяцы выводил и в Colab?

Comment: @svil, я не работал в Colab...

Comment: Зашла снова на Colab, спустя два часа как оставила код, а там нормальная полная ежемесячная разбивка по странам. Запустила снова - опять сокращенная по декабрям

Answer (score 0):

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.InvoiceDate)
data.drop('InvoiceDate', axis=1, inplace=True)

data['TotalCost'] = data['Quantity'] * data['UnitPrice']

data.groupby(['Country', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['TotalCost'].sum()
```

Если индекс стоит как DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex не нужно писать 'key=date'